# How do you find the exact value of x' if the equation of x has different variables in the equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Where I am struggling is the fact that $r$ and $p$ are different variables in a particular equation.
The problem is:  Find the exact value of p'(2) if p = sqrt ((1+r)/(2+r))

Do I use the limit definition of derivatives for this problem and then plug the 2 in?
Would p' be p(r).

I am asking this because I wanna double make sure that I did it right because I got the derivative as (1/2(sqrt(1+r/2+r)) as the answer. Do I plug the 2 in?

Comment: Could you please include some extra information such as the original equation?

Comment: Enclose TeX in \$, not `.

Comment: Are you taking the derivative of $p(r)$ with respect to $r$?  If so, then the names don't really matter (they're just names) and you could replace the $p$ by $f$ and the $r$ by $x$ to turn it into $f(x)$.